# I just got an Error Syntax near in a query

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I have an error inside MySQL query but I can't figure out what is it

The Error is

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'sin( radians(30.9006547) ) * sin( radians(lat
>   itude) ) ) ,8) as distance   FROM ' at line 3

Query is

```
SELECT h.*
     , ROUND(1.609344 * 3956 * acos( cos( radians(30.9006547) ) * cos( radians(latitude) ) * 
cos( radians(longitude) - radians(30.8524007) ) sin( radians(30.9006547) ) * sin( radians(latitude) ) ) ,8) as distance 
  FROM helper h
 where is_available = 1 
   and is_active = 1 
   and is_approved = 1 
   and ROUND((1.609344 * 3956 * acos( cos( radians(30.9006547) ) * cos( radians(latitude) ) * 
cos( radians(longitude) - radians(30.8524007) )sin( radians(30.9006547) ) * sin( radians(latitude) ) ) ) ,8) <= 60
 order 
   by distance LIMIT 3;
```

Comment: there is no `31` in the query you quoted...

Comment: I know i just take it out you mean the latitude and long

Comment: I have a geo_distance_km() function on my database. It saves a lot of typing. Just sayin'. Also, it's pretty obvious that something is missing immediately to the left of the sin

Comment: Can you please tell me if it possible? and how to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your code you missind the `+` sign between cos() and sin()

```
  SELECT h.*
       , ROUND(1.609344 * 3956 * acos( cos( radians(30.9006547) ) * cos( radians(latitude) ) * 
  cos( radians(longitude) - radians(30.8524007) ) +  /*<<<<<< here */
  sin( radians(30.9006547) ) * sin( radians(latitude) ) ) ,8) as distance 
    FROM helper h
   where is_available = 1 
     and is_active = 1 
     and is_approved = 1 
     and ROUND((1.609344 * 3956 * acos( cos( radians(30.9006547) ) * cos( radians(latitude) ) * 
  cos( radians(longitude) - radians(30.8524007) ) + /* <<<< and here */
   sin( radians(30.9006547) ) * sin( radians(latitude) ) ) ) ,8) <= 60
   order 
     by distance LIMIT 3;
```

Comment: Still   Error in query (1064): Syntax error near '( radians(31.50546547) ) * sin( radians(latitude) ) ) ) ,8) <= 60 order ' at line 10

Comment: answer update ....... the same + sign is missing in the where condition  ..  so add  the + in the proper place

Comment: and if you look better you see that the error message is not the same  the second show a different part of code  (for the same error code)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a function for calculating distances on Earth, in km. If you like it, use it... and don't forget to change your delimiter before and after constructing the function...

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `geo_distance_km`(lat1 double, lon1 double, lat2 double, lon2 double) RETURNS double
begin
   declare R int DEFAULT 6372.8;
   declare phi1 double;
   declare phi2 double;
   declare d_phi double;
   declare d_lambda double;
   declare a double;
   declare c double;
   declare d double;
   set phi1 = radians(lat1);
   set phi2 = radians(lat2);
   set d_phi = radians(lat2-lat1);
   set d_lambda = radians(lon2-lon1);
   set a = sin(d_phi/2) * sin(d_phi/2) +
         cos(phi1) * cos(phi2) *
         sin(d_lambda/2) * sin(d_lambda/2);
   set c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1-a));
   set d = R * c;
   return d;
   end
```

Comment: Oh really thank you and I'm really sorry I'm so noob at MySQL I'm just learning i don't know where to put it like the function I'm using node.js and i think I lack MySQL basics and if I'm gonna use it can I get like if the user active and approved? Like the query i posted above

Comment: Yep, you just call the function in place of all that ROUND(...acos...lat..) stuff.

Comment: Thank you! I will figure it out <3